# Angular 2 Unhandled Promise rejection: a[i] is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

Have been getting this error for for some days now. Here is a snapshot of the error:

I've gone through all the areas i think the problem could come from  (components and router) in my code without success. Looking for pointer on where i can look to. Willing to provide additional info when requested.

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: where is your code ? please post some code before posting question

Comment: Angular error messages can be frustratingly cryptic. When exactly do you get this error message, when the app starts, or along the way somewhere? Because it's a [ i ], "a" indicates to me it might be minified/uglified. Maybe, I would turn that off, try a build, run it, and see if you get the error, you might get some more info. That is, unless the vendor script is already minified. However, going into the debugger (assuming you have all your maps set up), and putting breakpoints/logs along the way, can help you track it down. You can at least figure out what happens right before the error.

Comment: Somewhere though (as I'm sure you know), you (or some script you use) are either submitting an empty array to something that expects it to have at least one item, you have an array with an undefined value in one of the indexes and it isn't checking to make sure it skips it, or you are overshooting the end of the array into undefined territory. All I see is "AppModule", so I'm betting it's in your startup routines somewhere (unless you just load everything in your AppModule...which isn't a good idea). FYI if you dont know how to use the debugger and maps, you're at a HUGE disadvantage.

Comment: @TimConsolazio I get the error when the app starts. I'm sure it has something to do with my root component. However, i'll try your suggestions and hope the problem is resolved. Will update the question with any new developement